# How to install MATLAB

Tags: 11.10, software-installation, matlab

I have Ubuntu 11.10 and try to install MATLAB 2011a. I followed the instructions on the PDF manual accompanying MATLAB as well as the topic at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MATLAB.

The problem is when I run

```
sudo /matlab_install_root/install
```

I get the message

```
sudo: /matlab_install_root/install: command not found
```

Is that an issue of incompatibility?

Cheers,

Comment: the link said to run `sudo /media/MATHWORKS_R2011A/install` - where have you got `/matlab_install_root/install` from?

Comment: Use FreeMat.It is much faster,readily available in Ubuntu Software Center and works similar to MATLAB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay guys. I got the problem.

I had the installation folder on an NTFS volume which wouldn't allow me to change the permissions to run the install thing. I moved the folder to an ext4 volume and everything was alright.

For those who have the same problem: don't forget to set the executable bit of the `sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/bin` or `sys/java/jre/glnx86/jre/bin` (depending on your architecture) directory, otherwise you would get some 'permission denied' or 'unknown command' error.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try?

> sudo ./matlab_install_root/install

Don't forget the dot.

Answer (score 0):

you said "I had the installation folder on an NTFS volume which wouldn't allow me to change the permissions to run the install thing" , when you want to write in any ntfs format drive you need to make it suitable by getting permission read and write by installing "ntfs configuration tool" you may get help from [this link](http://www.ubunturoot.com/2010/11/fix-ntfs-configuration-tool-in-ubuntu.html).

Answer (score 0):

Alternately you could, if you are desperate of course, purchase the windows version of MATLAB and try installing it using Wine.

If you don't already have Wine copy (ctrl+C) and paste (ctrl+shift+V) the following commands into terminal (ctrl+alt+T):

```
sudo apt-get install wine
```